# How do I align my forms so that they look like this?

Tags: html, css

[image: My current layout]

Hey, so I'm trying to build a movie review site which uses a database (I'm using PouchDB) and I want to style my admin/add a review page so that the inputs and labels are all aligned in a certain way. I keep adjusting widths, padding and margins but I just cant seem to get them to align. Can someone teach me how to align them the way i want them to be please?

This is how I want them to look:

[image: desired layout]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: georgia, arial;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  text-align: center;
}

.newFilm {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
}

label {
  padding: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
}

.form {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

input {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="newFilm">
  <h2 id='formTitle'>Create new review</h2>
  <div class="form">
    <form>
      <label for="title">Title:</label><input type="text" id="title">
      <label for="genre">Genre:</label><input type="text" id="genre">
      <label for="image">Image:</label><input type="text" id="image">
      <label for="rating">Rating:</label><input type="number" id="rating">
      <label for="synopsis">Synopsis:</label><input type="text" id="synopsis">
      <label for="trailer">Trailer:</label><input type="text" id="trailer">
      <input type="hidden" id="id">
      <button id="modifyFilmButton">Post review!</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Modified your html a little to add some structure. 
I would not recommend using this code, look into bootstrap tables, or something of that nature. It will look better, and be a more scaleable solution.

```css
.newFilm {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

textarea,
input,
label {
  display: block
}

textarea,
input {
  width: 200px;
}

.form {
  width: 100%;
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 49%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="newFilm">
  <h2 id='formTitle'>Create new review</h2>
  <div class="form">
    <form>
      <div class="left">
        <label for="title">Title:</label>
        <input type="text" id="title">
        <label for="genre">Genre:</label>
        <input type="text" id="genre">
        <label for="image">Image:</label>
        <input type="text" id="image">
        <label for="rating">Rating:</label>
        <input type="number" id="rating">
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <label for="synopsis">Synopsis:</label>
        <input type="text" id="synopsis">
        <label for="trailer">Trailer:</label>
        <textarea id="trailer" rows="5"></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" id="id">
        <button id="modifyFilmButton">Post review!</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Responsive solution:

```css
.myForm {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid myForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg"><h1>Create New Review</h1></div>
  </div>
  <form>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md"> <!-- left column -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Title</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Genre</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Image</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Rating</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md"> <!-- right column -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Synopsis</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Trailer</label>
          <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" disabled>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Adjust the left/right columns to have your desired effect.
See: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Slight problem though... When the page is resized (i.e taken into phone screen size) the text areas overlap each other, how do you go about fixing that so that the form is responsive?

Maybe drop the textareas into the same column when screen reaches a certain size?

Answer (score 1):

you can use either flex or grid or both. I've used both just as an example. you could also use only grid and nest a grid within a grid.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: georgia, arial;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  text-align: center;
}

.newFilm {
  background-color: green;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 10%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 30px;
}
#formTitle {
  grid-column: 1/3;
}
#modifyFilmButton {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  width: 50%;
  justify-self: end;
}
.left {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: left;
}
.right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>temp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="temp.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="newFilm">
      <h2 id="formTitle">Create new review</h2>

      <div class="left">
        <label for="title">Title:</label><input type="text" id="title" />
        <label for="image">Image:</label><input type="text" id="image" />
        <label for="trailer">Trailer:</label><input type="text" id="trailer" /> <input type="hidden" id="id" />
        <label for="rating">Rating:</label><input type="number" id="rating" />
      </div>

      <div class="right">
        <label for="genre">Genre:</label><input type="text" id="genre" />
        <label for="synopsis">Synopsis:</label><input type="text" id="synopsis" />
      </div>
      
      <button id="modifyFilmButton">Post review!</button>

      </div>

    <script src="temp.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well there are couple ways to do that.

My best option would be to have one big `div` that would hold two smaller `divs`.
Then give those two `divs` `width` of 50% each - i have used `grid` for that.
After that you want to make sure that `label` and `input` are taking full `width` of their container.
Like that you will achieve most of what you want. Also for Synopsis you should use `textarea` not `input`.

Here is my example on [codepen.](https://codepen.io/chelios-the-bashful/pen/bOKWgV?editors=1000)

Comment: @zee i deleted it accidentally, here i edited link with new codepen. not exactly the same code but same efficiency. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: georgia, arial;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  text-align: center;
}

.newFilm {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
}

label {
  padding: 6px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.form {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.col {
  padding: 20px;
}

input,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px;
}

#modifyFilmButton {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="newFilm">
  <h2 id='formTitle'>Create new review</h2>
  <div class="form">
    <form>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <label for="title">Title:</label><input type="text" id="title">
          <label for="image">Image:</label><input type="text" id="image">
          <label for="trailer">Trailer:</label><input type="text" id="trailer">
          <label for="rating">Rating:</label><input type="number" id="rating">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <label for="genre">Genre:</label><input type="text" id="genre">
          <label for="synopsis">Synopsis:</label>
          <textarea rows="9" id="synopsis"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" id="id">
      <button id="modifyFilmButton">Post review!</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```